# Trying to insert class on element through variable

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to add Class on section with id's by click of `<a>` tag and remove if clicks on other `<a>` tag. I'm getting the element in console But don't know why it's not taking class through jquery.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top scrolling-navbar bg-white">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#features">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#portfolios">Works</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#subscribe">Subscribe</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</nav>

  <section id="features" class="section">
  </section>

  <section id="portfolios" class="section">
  </section>

  <section id="team" class="section">
  </section>

  <div id="subscribe" class="section">
  </div>

  <section id="contact" class="section">
  </section>
```

```js
var clicktarget = $(".navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .nav-link");

   $(clicktarget).click(function(e){
    let target = $(this).attr('href');
    let hidepanel = $("body").find("section[id='" + target + "']"); 
    e.preventDefault();
    $(hidepanel).addClass("styleb"); 
    console.log(hidepanel);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here. Firstly there is no element with the class `navbar-expand-md` - although I assume this is just omitted from your example HTML.

Secondly you're double-wrapping a couple of your jQuery objects. If a variable already holds a jQuery object, such as `clicktarget` or `hidepanel`, you can access it's jQuery methods directly without needing to use `$()` again.

Thirdly you can simplify the id attribute selector to just use the `attr()` value directly, as it is already in the required format to use.

Lastly if only one `.section` should be shown at a time you'll need to call `removeClass()` on the current one to hide it.

With all that said, try this:

```js
var $clicktarget = $(".navbar-nav .nav-link");

$clicktarget.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $('.styleb').removeClass('styleb');
  let target = $(this).attr('href');
  $(target).addClass("styleb");
});
```

```css
.section {
  display: none;
}
.section.styleb {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#features">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#portfolios">Works</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#subscribe">Subscribe</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<section id="features" class="section">Features</section>
<section id="portfolios" class="section">Portfolios</section>
<section id="team" class="section">Team</section>
<div id="subscribe" class="section">Subscribe</div>
<section id="contact" class="section">Contact</section>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

- On click of a link you can get the href and you can use it directly inside the selector to select the section.

  `var target=$(this).attr('href');
          $(target).addClass("styleb");`
- Just inside the click function remove the class of the section by selecting it using the applied class

`$('.styleb').removeClass('styleb')`

```js
   $('a').click(function(e){
   $('.styleb').removeClass('styleb')
    var target=$(this).attr('href');
    $(target).addClass("styleb"); 
  });
```

```css
.styleb
{
color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#features">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#portfolios">Works</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#subscribe">Subscribe</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <section id="features" class="section">
  a
  </section>

  <section id="portfolios" class="section">
  v
  </section>

  <section id="team" class="section">
  f
  </section>

  <div id="subscribe" class="section">
  s
  </div>

  <section id="contact" class="section">
  </section>
```